# Formatting Data in DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I created a data set from an xml file and attached it to a gridview. I would like to do how do i format the data in the dataset or from the gridview, for example, change the header text for a column or also show only certain items in my gridview.

```
Dim xmlDataSet As New DataSet
xmlDataSet.ReadXml(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl)
GridView1.DataSource = xmlDataSet
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Is there anyway how to go about manipulating the data inside a dataset? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with theses posts :

First definition : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0sdh0b.aspx

Note : it's very interessant to read theses links about methods and properties

link  1 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

link 2 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataset.tables.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for renaming columns:

```
xmlDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["CurrentColumnName"].ColumnName = "NewColumnName";
```

Here is a way to hide or show columns:

```
xmlDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = true;
```